# Powershell 'for each' loop output without heading

Tags: powershell, for-loop

i am having a problem with the output of for-each loop. i am getting the desired output but for the parameters that I have selected, the heading appears before each line which i don't want.

**here's my code:**

```
$list = Get-Content C:\Temp\Description\Servers.txt
Foreach ($server in $list)
{
Get-ADComputer -identity $server -properties * | select name,description | ft -autosize
}
```

**please see image below for current and desired output**

[Output I am getting & the one I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1ncb.png)

Comment: just remove `| ft -autosize` you dont need it there and is causing your issue

Comment: Just FYI. Avoid format commands whenever possible. I have been programming in PowerShell for over 5 years and have never ever used format commands.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: Requesting you to put that as an answer ; so that night-fury can accept it and we have it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Santiago Squarzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)n commented, you don't need `Format-Table`, unless there are more than three columns. In this case PowerShell would default to list format and you'd have to force it to table format using `Format-Table`.

So this should work in your case:

```sh
$list = Get-Content C:\Temp\Description\Servers.txt
Foreach ($server in $list)
{
    Get-ADComputer -identity $server -properties * | select name,description
}
```

In cases where you actually have to use `Format-Table` to force the desired output, make sure that it is the **last command** of the pipeline:

```sh
Get-Content C:\Temp\Description\Servers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADComputer -identity $_ -properties * | select name,description
} | Format-Table -autosize
```